# button getting change but not text in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React JS and trying to implement basic login button and text according to login status, button text is getting changed but the welcome text is not being changed (this is importing from another file). see my code below.

#### LoginControl.js

```
import React from 'react';

import Greeting from './Greeting';

function LoginButton(props) {
    return <button onClick={props.onClick}>Login</button>;
}

function LogoutButton(props) {
    return <button onClick={props.onClick}>Logout</button>;
}

class LoginControl extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLoginClick = this.handleLoginClick.bind(this);
    this.handleLogoutClick = this.handleLogoutClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {isLoggedIn: false};
  }

  handleLoginClick() {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: true});
  }

  handleLogoutClick() {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: false});
  }

  render() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
    let button = null;
    if(isLoggedIn) {
        button = <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />;
    } else {
        button = <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;
    }
    return (
      <div>
          <Greeting isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
          {button}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginControl;
```

#### Greeting.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
function UserGreeting() {
  return <h1>Welcome back!</h1>;
}

function GuestGreeting() {
  return <h1>Please sign up.</h1>;
}

function Greeting(props) {
    const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedin;
    if(isLoggedIn) {
        return <UserGreeting />;
    } else {
        return <GuestGreeting />;
    }
}

export default Greeting;
```

#### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import LoginControl from './LoginControl';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <section>
          <LoginControl />
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Is this happening because I am using same const `isLoggedIn` in both 2 files

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Your prop is called `isLoggedIn` but you are trying to evaluate the variable `isLoggedin` which fails and thus gives you `false` to your local variable.

Just fix your typo and it will work.

Comment: Oh my !!. Thanks. does using same const variable name in 2 different file does not create any issue while importing other files in one file?

Comment: Having the same prop in different React components is not a problem. The typo error is the only thing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this. it works

```
function Greeting(props) {
    const {isLoggedIn} = props;
    if(isLoggedIn) {
        return <UserGreeting />;
    } else {
        return <GuestGreeting />;
    }
}
```

Comment: by this, we are assigning all props object  in `isLoggedIn` ? isn't it?

Comment: No, it will assign isLoggedIn value from props to const. read more here http://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/

Comment: Wow, this is kool. Thanks